# Boostrap css doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I installed `npm install bootstrap --save`
and added (below) to `index.html` but the styles doesn't change.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**My code (in other file):**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Only when I add this (below) to index.html, all works but the first web's load is very slow:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Update: (More details)**

The file bootstrap.min.css does exsist but the console says it cant find it.

**Folders Strucure:**
There is main folder is ang2project and inside it there are node_modules folder and src folder that contain the index.html

```
-angular2_projects
   -node_modules
          -bootstrap
              -dist
                 -css
                    bootstrap.min.css
   -src
          -index.html
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the file path `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` to see if its there?

Comment: are you sure this file exists.Have you checked you console for any errors?Try to locate the above file to see if it exists

Comment: Remember that your href is a relative path, so it needs to be visible from the current path/folder of your html

Comment: are you using it in a simple HTML or JSP or what else..?

Comment: Are index.html and node_modules folder in same location ?

Comment: @theblindprophet the file is there but the console says it cant find it. the main folder is ang2project and inside it there are node_modules folder and src folder that contain the index.html

Comment: provide a minimal structure of your paths. From index.html to boostrap.min.css